# Encode a string with accents and money symbols and returns a FileStreamReturn(MemoryStream) MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, csv, character-encoding, stringbuilder

I have this code:

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

output.AppendLine("Saldo a disposición: 23.15€");

[...]

System.Text.UnicodeEncoding en = new UnicodeEncoding();
byte[] byteArray = en.GetBytes(output.ToString());
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
string filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").ToUpper() + ".csv";

stream.Flush();
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/vnd.ms-excel") { FileDownloadName = filename};
```

When I open the document the symbol "€" and the accent in "disposión" don't appears. It seems like that:

> Saldo a disposiciï¿½n: 23.15ï¿½

Does anyone tell me how to do this?

Thank you!!

Comment: Does it make a difference if you encode in UTF8?

Comment: No, no difference. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
string filename = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").ToUpper() + ".csv";

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

StreamWriter output = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, 2 << 22);
output.WriteLine("Column1,Column2");
output.WriteLine("value for column one,\"Saldo a disposición: 23.15€\"");
output.WriteLine("another row col 1,another row col 2");
output.Flush();

stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/octet-stream") { FileDownloadName = filename };
```

Seems to be the encoding.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: I keep going wrong in Excel, but if you open it with a text editor I get well formatted text.
Why can it be?

Comment: Try using return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/octet-stream") ?  It's not an excel binary file.

Comment: Also worth making sure your output meets the guidelines of the CSV format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: I reviewed everything and I changed to content type than you send me and is still wrong.

It may be any configuration of pc?
When I save the file in the server and I open it, the file is ok (with correct symbols and accents), but when I try to download directly without saving the document in the server is when fails.

Comment: Seems like excel is very sensitive to the UTF8 encoding.  I revised my answer based and have tested this in a basic mvc app.  It seems to work fine when you use the stream writer approach which specifically targets utf-8 encoding.

Comment: Did you try out my revised answer?  I changed this answer, the new code works perfect for me when opening in excel.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have time, Now  I'll be try to do like you say